# Hyperledger composer in multiple host (local network)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am a biginner in block chain development. I see many examples and git in hyperledger fabric. I whish to learn hyperledger composer and it working. And I want to apply this in my local network (multiple host) . Then I searched many documents and website regarding this topic. But nothing to find. Please help me as possible with suitable examples
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are the guides that I followed to deploy the Hyperledger Fabric on Multi-Host

[Deploy Hyperledger Blockchain into Multiple-Org](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org)

[Hyperledger Fabric on Multiple Hosts](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f)

I used the Fabric SDK from the first link, I combined the guide to the second link where you have to create a docker swarm and download some script.

Comment: Hey Thanks for answering

Comment: Actually I need help in hyperledger composer. Not in hyperledger fabric.

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy Hyperledger Composer networks in a multiple host network on its own. But you can configure a Hyperledger Fabric network in a multi-host network and then deploy your composer network on it since Hyperledger Composer is just a tool for configuring blockchain network on top of Hyperledger Fabric.

This [post](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f) has a good example of a multi-host Hyperledger Composer network.